# Why does a "Congratulation You Passed" review item show up in my flag list to be reviewed?

Tags: bug, flags, review-audits

The last week, I have noticed a slight change in behaviour for the test messages in the review queue.  It may be low quality posts, but I am not 100% sure.

Anyhow, a question I flagged today came back as "Congratulations ..." because it was a test to assure people are doing quality reviews.  I clicked on the link, and "Page Not Found" is what I got because the question really did get removed a while ago I presume.

Well, I click on flags to see which flags are under review, and this same test review item, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260665/cant-login-modx-manager-redirect, shows up as needing review.

I assume this a bug and we don't need to review test posts which have already been removed?

Comment: There's a problem with [review audits allowing the action to complete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231829/users-under-10k-flagging-posts-that-were-deleted-by-review-several-weeks-before). It's not supposed to let you actually submit the flag, but rather instantly complete when you click the flag button.

Comment: @animuson - Worse still, I see "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" for this item!  I had no choice, the moderator option was the only one available to me ...

Comment: Well, writing "blah blah blah" as the flag reason doesn't exactly convey any sort of message to moderators. I'm sure it looked like a bogus flag to that moderator.